# How to work where conditions simultaneously in a LINQ C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
Page curpage = new Page();
History history = (History)curpage.Session["history"];

List<TreatmentLedger> hasvalidrows = 
 (from h in history.Rows where h.Status != 11 && h.displayStatus != "" select h).ToList();
```

its not working i need the rows without have  `status!=11 and displayStatus !=""`

if `status==11` and `displayStatus =="unsaved`".it must be a valid row.

if  `status==11` and `displayStatus ==""`.it must be a invalid row.

if `status!=11` and `displayStatus =="unsaved".`it must be a valid row.

if  `status!=11` and `displayStatus ==""`.it must be a valid row.
pls help me.

```
    List<TreatmentLedger> hasvalidrows = (from h in history.Rows where (h.Status != 11 || h.displayStatus != "")  select h).ToList();--its working
```

but now i have another condition

if `status==11` and `displayStatus =="unsaved`" and id !=0.it must be a valid row.
if `status==11` and `displayStatus =="unsaved`" and id ==0.it must be a invalid row.

if  `status==11` and `displayStatus ==""`.it must be a invalid row.

if `status!=11` and `displayStatus =="unsaved".`it must be a valid row.

if  `status!=11` and `displayStatus ==""`.it must be a valid row.

Comment: so write all that in your where clause....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if status==11 and displayStatus =="unsaved".it must be a valid row.

then you need to use the logical **OR** :

```
List hasvalidrows = (from h in history.Rows 
                     where h.Status != 11 || h.displayStatus != "" select h).ToList();
```

This way either the one or the other has to be at least valid to make the entire row valid

Comment: its working.if i have an another condition like this.

if  status==11 and displayStatus =="unsaved" and id !=0. it must be a valid row.

if  status==11 and displayStatus =="unsaved" and id ==0. it must be a invalid row

Comment: @shalushaji I am glad that it works for you. It can sometimes be confusing. Because we tend to use the natural language not always in a clear logical fashion. you can extend this to include `id != 0` but be carefull whether it is **AND** or **OR**

Comment: List<TreatmentLedger> hasvalidrows = (from h in history.Rows where h.Status != 11 || h.displayStatus != "" || h.id !=0 select h).ToList();
            Its not working.i cant understand the logic behind this.normaly we use && --meaning need both conditions are true and ||---any of one true,it return true.

Comment: look at your example "if status==11 and displayStatus =="unsaved".it must be a valid row." only one of the 2 condition is met and you have a valid row! so you need to use or. if `id !=0` is mandatory you need to combine it with the rest with an **AND** like this: `where (h.Status != 11 || h.displayStatus != "") && h.id !=0 select h`

Comment: its not working
        List<TreatmentLedger> hasvalidrows = (from h in history.Rows where (h.Status != 11 || h.displayStatus != "") && h.id !=0  select h).ToList();
if status==0 and dispalystatus="unsaved" and id=0 it return nothing

Comment: @shalushaji so it seems that it is not mandatory. You need to be clear about what you want. how important is the condition `id != 0` ? does it have to be true in all cases? if yes use **AND** otherwise, if one of the conditions can be false, like in your last example `id = 0` you need to use **OR**

Comment: @shalushaji I don't really understand why: "(from h in history.Rows where h.Status != 11 || h.displayStatus != "" || h.id !=0 select h).ToList(); Its not working." can you post the line where it failed?

Comment: @shalushaji I just saw your edit, please include the id constraint into the last 3 examples

Comment: List<TreatmentLedger> hasvalidrows = (from h in history.Rows where h.Status != 11 || h.displayStatus != "" select h).ToList();
        hasvalidrows = (from hs in hasvalidrows where hs.id != 0 || hs.Status != 11 select hs).ToList();
now its working

Comment: @shalushaji looking at your example, the former version with 3 times `||` should also work, because you are only iterating `||` twice in the new version. Are you sure that you tested it correctly in the first place?

Comment: if a new row add to the list with outsaving .the id=0 and displaystatus="unsaved" and status =0.user also can delete without saving the row.
 .after saving the row, the id has a value greater than 0 and displaystatus="" and status=2.,if the user delete the row without saving its not a valid row.but if the row already saved and edited then changed its displaystatus to unsaved only,not id and status.and user also can i delete this row without deleting..sow my condition is the current is saved or not and id=0 or not and displaystatus=unsaved or not.

Comment: now its working with another linq.
     
List<TreatmentLedger> hasvalidrows = (from h in history.Rows where h.Status != 11 || h.displayStatus != "" select h).ToList(); hasvalidrows = (from hs in hasvalidrows where hs.id != 0 || hs.Status != 11 select hs).ToList();

Comment: i just added another linq with the first one.

Comment: @shalushaji looking at your example, the former version with 3 times || should also work, because you are only iterating || twice in the new version. Are you sure that you tested it correctly in the first place? –Yes i tested